# Meaning of "take trains like the Twentieth Century"

Tags: meaning, short-stories, jack-finney

In the short story 'The Third Level' By Jack Finney, there is a sentence given as such:

> I turned into Grand Central from Vanderbilt Avenue, and went down the steps to the first level, where you take trains like the Twentieth Century.

Please elaborate on 'where you take trains like the Twentieth Century'?

PS: I'm an Indian, so I'm unable to relate to Western culture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passage apparently refers to the [20th Century Limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20th_Century_Limited), an express passenger train that ran between New York and Chicago.

> The *20th Century Limited* was an express passenger train on the New York Central Railroad (NYC) from 1902 to 1967. The train traveled between Grand Central Terminal in New York City and LaSalle Street Station in Chicago, Illinois, along the railroad's "Water Level Route".